# How to show a 404 instead of a 403 on apache host

Tags: http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403, errors

My site was hacked about 2 months ago so I closed the site down but there are over 1,000 spam links out there still directing to the domain. As there are no files on the domain visitors, including Google, receive a 403 error, so assume the page exists. How can I change the 403 to a 404? I have a `404.html` file and have tried all the different rewrite, error document variations for the `htaccess` file I've been able to find on this site and others and nothing seems to work. For example:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?fineartdecor.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ - [R=404,NC]

------------------------------

ErrorDocument 404 /index.html?status=404

-------------------------------

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA]

--------------------------------
```

Further suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

It is producing the 403 error because:

1. Your directory is empty, or
2. `htaccess` is blocking access, or
3. You simply don't have an `index.htm`.

So release the `htaccess`, and create a bare bones `index.html` that states that you were a victim and basically what your intentions are (i.e. we will be back soon bigger, better, and safer). After that lack of specific pages will result in a 404.  Everything else will result in the index.html being displayed.